# Logistic Regression- multiclass-multioutput is not supported + errors

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, logistic-regression

I am new to python and while doing a Logistic Regression I'm having a few issues, such as displayed. Here's my code, and then the error messages:

```
 import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
    from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, roc_auc_score
    
X = dataset_df
Y = dataset_df

'X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test\
= train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=1)'

X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation\
= train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size = 0.3, random_state=1)

sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train_Std = sc.transform(X_train)

lr_classifier = LogisticRegression(C = 1000, random_state= 1)
rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, random_state= 1)
rf_classifier.fit(X_train_Std, y_train)

rf_classifier.predict_proba(sc.transform(X_validation))
```

then here

```
roc_auc_score(y_true=y_test, y_score=lr_2.predict(X_test_std_pca_1))
```

**NameError: name 'lr_2' is not defined**

and there

```
max_depth_params = [2, 3, 5 ,10]

for max_depth in max_depth_params:
    rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=max_depth, random_state= 1)
    rf_classifier.fit(X_train_Std, y_train)
    y_pred2 = rf_classifier.predict(sc.transform(X_validation))
    
    print('max depth param:', max_depth, 'accuracy:', accuracy_score(y_true=y_validation, y_pred=y_pred2))
```

**ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported**

and there

```
lr_classifier.fit(X_train_Std, y_train)
y_pred = lr_classifier.predict(sc.transform(X_validation))
```

**ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (3876, 16) instead.**

and finally :

```
y_pred2 = rf_classifier.predict(sc.transform(X_validation))

print('Misclassified samples {0} out of {1}, i.e. {2:.2f}% accurate'.\
      format((y_validation != y_pred).sum(), len(y_validation), (1 - (y_validation != y_pred).sum()/len(y_validation))*100))
```

TypeError: **unsupported format string passed to Series.**format****

so many messages of error that i feel as if my head is going to explode, if someone could help i'd be very grateful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Variable name error `lr_2` is not variable name you have defined it as `lr_classifier`
2. Your `Target` or `y` is not single column but it's 2D (`Multiclass`)
3. It clearly states the issue that `y` is not `1D array`
4. Unsupported datatype is passed probably an `Series`.

And try to debug errors one at a time and learn `python` basic before going to `Machine Learning` please.